# How to parse unstructured JSON in APEX

Tags: apex

Hello I have below json in api:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"297968",
         "type":"email_from_class",
         "extra":[

         ],
         "sessionid":null,
         "canBeDeleted":true
      },
      {
         "id":"297919",
         "type":"microsite_email_opened_class",
         "extra":{
            "Prescribing Information":[
               {
                  "id":"599",
                  "name":"abc",
                  "type":"pdf",
                  "description":"abx",
                  "subtitle":"PI",
                  "content":"",
                  "thumb":""
               }
            ],
            "emailinfo":{
               "from":"",
               "to":"",
               "emailSentDate":"",
               "opened":[

               ]
            }
         },
         "sessionid":null,
         "canBeDeleted":true
      },
      {
         "id":"297848",
         "type":"microsite_email_class",
         "extra":{
            "Prescribing Information":[
               {
                  "id":"599",
                  "name":"",
                  "type":"",
                  "description":"",
                  "subtitle":"",
                  "content":"",
                  "thumb":""
               }
            ],
            "emailinfo":{
               "from":"",
               "to":"",
               "emailSentDate":"",
               "opened":[

               ]
            }
         },
         "sessionid":null,
         "canBeDeleted":true
      },
      {
         "id":"297847",
         "type":"sales_visit_class",
         "extra":[
            {
               "duration":"",
               "title":"New presentation started",
               "section":"",
               "hasrating":-1,
               "thumb":null,
               "extra":null
            },
            {
               "duration":28,
               "title":"Surveys",
               "section":null,
               "hasrating":-1,
               "thumb":null,
               "extra":null
            }
         ],
         "sessionid":"18540676-30bc-4bbc-bf72-c803f8e360b3",
         "canBeDeleted":true
      },
      {
         "id":"297811",
         "type":"email_open_class",
         "extra":{
            "from":"",
            "to":"",
            "cc":"",
            "bcc":"",
            "emailSentDate":"",
            "opened":[
               1561040954
            ],
            "locationinfo":{
               "1561040954":{
                  "ip":"",
                  "country":"",
                  "region":"",
                  "city":"",
                  "coordinates":"",
                  "mobile":false,
                  "browser_name":"",
                  "browser_version":"",
                  "platform":""
               }
            }
         },
         "sessionid":null,
         "canBeDeleted":true
      },
      {
         "id":"297808",
         "type":"email_to_class",
         "extra":{
            "from":"",
            "to":"",
            "cc":"",
            "bcc":"",
            "emailSentDate":"",
            "opened":[
               1561040954
            ]
         },
         "sessionid":null,
         "canBeDeleted":true
      }
   ],
   "indicators":{
      "total_activities":6
   }
}
```

In above json `extra` key's value is not static it has unstructured data so how can I parse it ?

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: How about [JSON.deseralizeUntyped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_deserializeUntyped) ?

Comment: Will it print data inside visualforce ?

Comment: Please update your post with what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4):

The fact that "type" is one of the keys - and is also a reserved keyword - tells you that yes you need to use `JSON.deserializeUntyped` anyway as Pranay suggested.

If a section contains unstructured data, you need to figure out what possible data structures you are willing to extract data from and then write Apex code to handle extracting them.

In general `deserializeUntyped` returns a `Map<String, Object>`. Each of the objects in the map can be either a primitive data type (e.g. `String`, `Integer`, `Decimal`, `Boolean`) or a `List<Object>` or another `Map<String,Object>`. You can test which one it is using `instanceof` on the objects, and then you have to cast it to the correct type in order to manipulate or inspect the data further. And then if it's one of the latter two types, you have to again take the objects inside of it and test/cast them.

Comment: One could work around `type` being a reserved word by replacing the json `"type":` with `"type_x":` and deserializing into a custom apex type - the real problem is that `extra` is either an array or a custom type(s) and deserializing into a top level custom apex type that includes a property defined as Object is not supported (sad) so as you say, Json.deserializedUntyped is the way to go.

Comment: Indeed. It would be lovely if I could just include a `Map<String,Object>` or `Object[]` in the type I deserialize to, and have it behave just like `deserializeUntyped`, but alas no.